# Python, how can I initialize a variable during function/method calls

Tags: python, function, syntax, initialization

In most interpreted languages (example given in psuedo PHP) I would be able to do something like this

```
function f($name, &$errors = null) {
    if(something_wrong) {
        if(!is_null($errors) {
            $errors[] = 'some error';
        }
        return false;
    }
}

if(!f('test', $errs = array()) {
    print_r($errs);
}
```

And get a result like

```
Array
(
     [0] => some error
)
```

However when I try this in Python

```
def f(name, errors = None):
    if something_wrong:
        if errors:
            errors.append('some error')
        return False


if not f('test', errs = []):
    print str(errs)
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errs'
```

Which makes perfect sense in the context of Python thinking I am trying to set a specific argument, and not create a new variable altogether.

However if I try

```
if not f('test', (errs = [])):
    print str(errs)
```

I get

```
    f('test', (errs = []))
                    ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because I think now it assumes I am trying to create a tuple.

**Is there any way to keep this code on one line, or do I absolutely have to initialise the variable on it's own before passing it to the function/method?** From what I can tell the only solution is this

```
errs = []
if not f('test', errs):
    print str(errs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "In Python, assignment is a statement, not an expression, and can
>   therefore not be used inside an arbitrary expression."

see http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm

Comment: Thank you pBuch, that's what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be called as `f(name, errors = [])` or `f(name, [])`. If you want to init with attribute name, python requires the variable key you given is same with any attribute name you declared in the function definition.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me, in fact you've completely removed the initialization of errs, so there's no way I can access it after the function call is completed.